# require_once is not responding in Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys in localhost each and everyting is going perfect but wehnever i am uploading the files into my Cpanel syas:

```
Warning: require_once(/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/ProDisPds/func.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/ProDisPds/func.php on line 2
```

NAME and PATH of the file is correct

Comment: Remove the leading slash

Comment: Using dirname(__ FILE __) will help to reduce repeating paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you said, PATH is wrong here

Current Path is this

```
/home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/ProDisPds/
```

and you are `require` ing

```
/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/config.php
```

Which is not correct from that reference.

Try

```
require_once("/home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/config.php");
```

Comment: great thanks alot now i can get the file but another problem increased if you don't mind please ???

Comment: Dear Hanky the url i have send you has got a prolem if you don't mind visit it

Answer (score 2):

You can define the path in two ways : relative or absolute path.

```
An absolute path refers to a file on the Internet using its full URL while 
relative path assumes that the file is on the current server
```

For more information of Relative and absolute path, you can refer [this link](http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/dgm/2120/IN/steinja/lessons/06/06_04.html).

Current directory :

```
/home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/ProDisPds/
```

So in that case, your path should be :

Either give absolute path :

```
require_once("/home/scalesgc/public_html/spdealers/Admin Panel/config.php");
```

Or use relative path:

```
require_once("../config.php");
```

Hope, it will solve your issue.